# No stack segment warning in MASM

Tags: assembly, stack, warnings, masm

I am a begginer in assembly.
Im trying to print a letter on screen with MASM. I defined the stack segment but when i trying to link the program, got this warning:

Link: Warning L4021: no stack segment

However the program works fine!
How can i fix this? Please explain in simple words. Thank You.

printa.asm:

```
stk segment
    DW 32 dup(?)
stk ends
cds     segment
    assume cs:cds,ss:stk
    main proc far
        mov ah,02
        mov dl, 'A'
        int 21h

        mov ah,01
        int 21h

        mov ah,4ch
        int 21h
    main endp
cds ends
END main
```

printa.lst:

```
Microsoft (R) Macro Assembler Version 6.00              11/06/15 09:38:16
printa.asm                           Page 1 - 1


 0000               stk segment
 0000  0020 [               DW 32 dup(?)
        0000
       ]
 0040               stk ends
 0000               cds     segment
                    assume cs:cds,ss:stk
 0000                   main proc far
 0000  B4 02                    mov ah,02
 0002  B2 41                    mov dl, 'A'
 0004  CD 21                    int 21h

 0006  B4 01                    mov ah,01
 0008  CD 21                    int 21h

 000A  B4 4C                    mov ah,4ch
 000C  CD 21                    int 21h
 000E                   main endp
 000E               cds ends
                END main
Microsoft (R) Macro Assembler Version 6.00              11/06/15 09:38:16
printa.asm                           Symbols 2 - 1




Segments and Groups:

                N a m e                 Size     Length   Align   Combine Class

cds  . . . . . . . . . . . . . .    16 Bit   000E     Para    Private 
stk  . . . . . . . . . . . . . .    16 Bit   0040     Para    Private 


Procedures,  parameters and locals:

                N a m e                 Type     Value    Attr

main . . . . . . . . . . . . . .    P Far    0000     cds   Length= 000E Private

       0 Warnings
       0 Errors
```

Comment: Instead of `stk segment`, try `STACK SEGMENT STACK USE16`, and then `ss:STACK` in your `assume` list.

Comment: From a deleted link-only answer: https://github.com/open-watcom/open-watcom-v2/issues/527#issuecomment-472077453.  Also: Official MASM reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/segment

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution.
We need to define the "combine type" for stack segment.

```
stk segment
```

Should be:

```
stk segment stack
```

The only combine type that works for stack segment is "stack".

Comment: Working perfect in masm

Answer (score 0):

```
assume cs:cds,ss:stk

stk segment STACK 'STACK'
    dw 32 dup(0)
stk ends

cds segment
main:
  mov ax,4c00h
  int 21h
cds ends

end main
```

[Synopsis](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/segment)(Official MASM reference)

**ref1:** According to [jmalak](https://github.com/open-watcom/open-watcom-v2/issues/527#issuecomment-472077453), the first `STACK` w/o quotation marks attaches a STACK [combine type attritute](http://www.plantation-productions.com/Webster/www.artofasm.com/DOS/ch08/CH08-2.html#HEADING2-164) to `stk` segment, while the second `'STACK'` w/ quotation marks attaches a class attribute to is.

**ref2:** Quote from [a detailed explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40829884/8243991) by [Margaret Bloom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5801661/margaret-bloom):

> STACK same as PUBLIC but in the binary generated, metadata are created so that the OS set SS:SP to the end of a segment using this attribute (after concatenation has taken place).
>
> The segment definition SSEG SEGMENT STACK 'STACK' defines a segment with:
>   * Name SSEG.
>   * Combination attribute STACK, making the linker emit metadata to set SS:SP to point to the end of it.
>   * Class attribute 'STACK' making the linker recognize it as a stack segment.

**However there is an ugly way to do it:**

```
assume cs:cds,ss:stk

stk segment
    dw 32 dup(0)
stk ends

cds segment
main:
  mov ss,stk ; (1)
  mov sp,64 ; (2)
  mov ax,4c00h
  int 21h
cds ends

end main
```

(1) (2) explicitely assigns [SS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86#Purpose):[SP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86#Purpose) in a manual fashion. SS <- Address of `stk` segment. SP <- Top address of the stack. Further push/pop will just work as normal.