# Assembly segment declaration syntax

Tags: assembly, emu8086

I just started with ASM, and x8086 architecture, and I'm having certain issues following up with some of the examples that come with emu8086.

```
SSEG    SEGMENT STACK   'STACK'
DW      100h    DUP(?)
SSEG    ENDS
```

Okay *SSeg* , I guess that it's a label to be the stack segment, the *SEGMENT* keyword to indicate that ahead comes a segment, but what does  `STACK 'STACK'` stand for?

And below, I think it means "Allocate (I don't know where) 100h 16 bit words, without values"
Is this correct and if so, where is it allocated?

Comment: http://www.phatcode.net/res/223/files/html/Chapter_8/CH08-2.html  .. About "allocate" - yes, it will reserve 512 bytes somewhere (*somewhere* in total memory, from the point of source it will be at the beginning of stack segment, because it's first byte defined inside SEGMENT -> ENDS block), linker + linker script will decide where to target "stack" segment, and then OS loader of executable will do the final relocation.

Comment: As the emu8086 is integrated package of: emulator, IDE, debugger, assembler, linker and thai massage of feets (maybe the last one was only in paid version), you are quite effectively cut out from the tiny details of compilation/linking/booting/loading_executable process, so unless you are really persistent, give up about those details ([here](http://courses.ee.sun.ac.za/OLD/2003/Rekenaarstelsels245/8086_Instruksies/memory.html) is total memory map of emulated machine in emu8086, but it doesn't answer how its DOS does load .exe and relocates it, check `cs/ds/ss` values in debugger).

Answer (score 4):

I assume that emu8086 supports, for declaring a segment, the same syntax as TASM does, which in turn supports the same syntax as MASM.

---

A segment is declared with `<name> SEGMENT [attributes]` or `SEGMENT <name> [attributes]`. The *attributes* are optional and default values are inferred if any is missing.

`<name>` can be any valid name not already defined (beware that the `.MODEL` directive defines some name, including *_TEXT* and *_DATA*).

The `[attributes]` are divided into five categories, each category has one or more values to chose from.
Values from different categories are separated by whitespaces, no more that a single value for any category can appear.

**Segment combination attribute**
These attribute values define how two or more segments are combined together.

- `PUBLIC` makes the linker concatenate segments with the same name defined in different modules (i.e. source files).
- `PRIVATE` the opposite of the above, segments with the same name defined outside of the current module will not be concatenated (note the in the same file segments with the same name are still considered the same segment).
- `STACK` same as `PUBLIC` but in the binary generated, metadata are created so that the OS set `SS:SP` to the end of a segment using this attribute (after concatenation has taken place).
- `MEMORY` either an alias for `STACK` and typo in TASM manual.
- `COMMON` all the segments with the same name will overlap instead of being concatenated. The final segment is as long as the longest `COMMON` segment.
- `VIRTUAL` is used to declare a segment that must appear only once in the final binary, regardless of how many times is declared in all the modules.
- `AT` places a segment at a specific address.
- `UNINIT` mark the segment as containing uninitialized data (just like the `.bss` section in the ELF)

**Segment class attribute**

This is a quoted string that represent the segment class. The segment class is a string meaningful for the linker only, it helps ordering and recognizing purpose of a segment when creating the metadata in the final binary file.
The classes the linker recognizes are:  `_TEXT`, `FAR_DATA`, `FAR_BSS`, `_DATA`, `CONST`, `_BSS` and `STACK`.

**Segment alignment attribute**
These values specify the alignment the segment must have.
In short they tell the linker at what multiple a segment can begin, for example `PARA`, for *paragraph*, 16 bytes, tells the linker that a segment can start at an address multiple of 16: 0, 16, 32, 48, ...

- `BYTE`, alignment of 1
- `WORD`, alignment of 2
- `DWORD`, alignment of 4
- `PARA`, alignment of 16
- `PAGE` alignment of 256
- `MEMPAGE` alignment of 4096

**Segment size attribute**
These values specify the size of the code and data of a segment.

- `USE16` tells the assembler that the code to be generated must be 16-bit and that the data accessed must use 16-bit address size.
- `USE32` the same as above but with 32-bit size.

**Segment access attributes**
These attributes, not supported by *TLINK*, tells the linker what access restriction put in the metadata for the segment.
This doesn't apply to DOS binaries.
The values are `EXECONLY`, `EXECREAD`, `READONLY`, `READWRITE`. The names are eloquent.

---

The segment definition `SSEG    SEGMENT STACK   'STACK'` defines a segment with:

- Name `SSEG`.
- Combination attribute `STACK`, making the linker emit metadata to set `SS:SP` to point to the end of it.
- Class attribute `'STACK'` making the linker recognize it as a stack segment.

---

Making the linker aware that a segment is a stack segment is done with the `STACK` combination and the `'STACK'` class.
The first controls the initial value of `SS:SP`<sup>1</sup> and would be enough to have a stack.
The second specify the ordering and the grouping of the segment itself.

**Segment grouping**

The linker can group segments together, this is just like concatenating the segments but respecting the alignment constraints.
By grouping segments together it is possible to use a single segment register to access all of them.
Segment grouping is also used to logically grouping the segment, i.e. making the linker treat them all the same.

Particularly, TASM implicitly defines the `DGROUP` group that when using the `.MODEL` directives includes, among others, the segments with class `'DATA'` and `'STACK'`.
You can excludes the `'STACK'` segments from the `DGROUP` with the `FARSTACK` option of the `.MODEL` directive.

So the class `'STACK'` tell the linker that the segment must go (or must not go) into the `DGROUP`.
Furthermore inside that group `'STACK'` segments are placed after any other segment class.

---

The final effect of the pair `STACK 'STACK'` is to:

1. Initialize `SS:SP`.
2. Placing the stack after the data.

---

The `DW      100h    DUP(?)` line just do what you said, the correct term however is *reserve* as I believe there is no space allocated in the binary file for the stack.  The linker may be smart enough to recognize that a `'STACK'` classed segment with uninitialized data don't need to take place on disk.
But I may be wrong, I don't remember exactly if the MZ header of the binary file would permit that.

Another simpler way to declare a stack segment of predefined size is `.STACK 200h` (or simply `.STACK` if you are ok with using 1KiB of stack).

---

[Chapter 7 of the TASM manual](http://bitsavers.trailing-edge.com/pdf/borland/turbo_assembler/Turbo_Assembler_Version_5_Users_Guide.pdf) has more complete info on this long topic.

---

<sup>1</sup> To better understand this point it's worth noting that the EXE generated has a header where the linker can specify the initial value for those registers and the OS will relocate and set them upon the loading of the binary.