# What is the meaning of assigning a segment name to a register in 8086 assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, segment, emu8086

I'm helping a friend with homework and in his code and I encountered a line I don't understand.
This is the code, roughly:

```
code segment    
assume cs: code, ds: data, ss: stack
...
mov ax, data
mov ds, ax
...

data segment
...
ends

stack segment
...
ends
```

emu8086 shows an error for `mov ax, data` for "wrong parameters". I guess that's because the data segment isn't defined yet. I want to know if I can simply remove these two lines as they seemingly do nothing and for. Thinking of this I realized I don't know what could assigning a segment mean and I don't find it online either.

(the data segment was originally the first but then the emulator tries to execute the data and fails because the data isn't in the form of valid instructions).

Comment: You should not remove it otherwise all your accesses will reference some random memory and not your data segment. Some assemblers use the syntax `mov ax, @data` maybe try that or consult your manual.

Comment: What assembler are you programming with?

Comment: @fuz We both use emu8086

Comment: In 16 bit real mode the physical memory address, when some instruction is accessing memory, is calculated as 20 bit integer = (segment<<4) + offset. So by using wrong `ds` value you will access different segments in memory, but not your "data". Through single segment value you can address only 64kiB of memory (16 bit offset = 0..65535), to access  more memory you need to use different segment values (up to 1MiB address space in 8086 16b real mode, theoretically)  Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40829884/4271923 (kinda misses some simplified example, OTOH it's quite complete)

Comment: But you can delete `assume`, that's MASM/TASM directive, which is not supported by emu8086 (it will be just ignored, so it's sort of harmless in your case, but if somebody used to MASM/TASM would actually try to use it in some more complex way, it would fail him). (I tried to google for some neat example, but failed, have found the common "emu8086" things which are only "good", but always make me frown on some detail or lack of some detail)